# Generate n tables of values ​for functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, syntax

After searching for a long time, I can't find how to do what I need with some bold header style.

I need to generate n tables of values ​​for linear functions (f(x)=mx+n), where x varies from -6 to 6, m and n and that I can choose whether m and n are integers or rational, with m different from zero.

this is what i have
m = -3;
n = 2;

```
tabla = Table[{x, m*x + n}, {x, -6, 6}];
Grid[Prepend[tabla, {"x", "y"}], Dividers -> All]
```

apart from the screen presentation, if they could also be exported to a folio size sheet (215mm x 330mm) it would be great, can you help me

edit :this would be enough, I need the program to make me choose between option 1: m and n integers between -5 and 5, without the zero and option 2: m and n rational I didn't calculate the tables, it's just the idea

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Pamela and welcome to MMA stack exchange. Firstly, Are you in  principle happy with the overall form of what your table produces? You are using "n" for both number of tables and the offset constant of your linear function. Could you:

1. Type out all the things you want to achieve, i.e. a) bold headers, b) exportable, ....
2. Give an example of a simple case scenario ideal solution. You could even type it out or provide a basic drawing that you can upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

integers = Select[Range[-5, 5], # != 0 &];
rationals = {-3/2, -2/5, -1/3, 1/3, 2/5, 3/2};

Column[Framed[Grid[Table[
      Table[
       {m, n} = RandomChoice[#, 2];
       Grid[Join[
         {{TraditionalForm@Style[StringForm["``", y == m*x + n], 14],
           SpanFromLeft},
          Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "y"}},
         Table[{x, m*x + n}, {x, -6, 6}]],
        Frame -> All],
       5], 2],
     Alignment -> Top]] & /@ {integers, rationals}]
```

[image]

Comment: hi, Thanks, it works for me too, but I'm looking for something like what I published in my edition

Comment: hi, Would you be so kind as to explain the code to me a bit? There are things I understand, others I don't.

Comment: If there is a command or an operator that you don't understand, highlight it with your mouse and press `F1` for help. If after reading the documentation there is something that you don't understand, ask a specific focused question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for but this is what I understood from it:

- I start by creating a function that does two things
  a. Generate the numbers exactly as your code does
  b. Create a single table which has the headers for x and y.

Then I do something a bit more complex:

- I create a Grid which uses the above function multiple times so that I can create the grid I want.
- I then add some fancy styling that converts your variables into a string.

Let me know if you want me to elaborate further.

```
myGrid[n_, m_ : -3] := 
 Grid[{Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}}~Join~
   Table[{x, m*x + n}, {x, -6, 6}], Dividers -> All] (* this is my function*);

{m, n} = {-3, 3} (* these are your  variable settings *);

Grid[{ToString[m] <> " x + " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range@n, 
  myGrid[#, m] & /@ Range@n}, Dividers -> All] (* create the final grid *)
```

[image]

---

Generally it is better to `Plot` your data rather than simply generate a list.

Please let me know if there is something that you don't understand or if there is something I misunderstood in your question.

Comment: hi, If it is almost what I need, there you created 3 tables, I need to create
 2 rows of 5 each, but that m and n are random integers (ideal that allows me to choose m and n between m and n integers or rational.
It would also be ideal if I let you choose if I want to see the equation in the header or not
(summary, possibility of showing or not the equations in the header, possibility of choosing between m and n integers (between -5 and 5) or rational)

Comment: @Pamela, I do not think I understand what you mean by 2 rows of 5 each. At the other answer you asked to show 10 in groups of 5 which is not easy to understand. Could you please provide more clarity to what exactly you are asking? Even a hand-drawn diagram would suffice.

At this stage you are asking us to create a piece of work rather than help you troubleshoot an issue. A bit more of an explanation could go a long way.

Comment: hi , see edition
I need the program to make me choose between option 1: m and n integers between -5 and 5, without the zero and
option 2: m and n rational


I didn't calculate the tables, it's just the idea